# How do I choose which Ethernet Adapter to bridge in VMPlayer

Tags: vmware-player

I am running vmplayer 3.1.0 on Ubuntu.  The host machine has four ethernet adapters that are configured to run on four different subnets.  I need to run four VMs each with a single ethernet adapter bridged onto a specific one of the physical ethernet adapters.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Am I simply exceeding the capabilities of vmplayer and have to go to one of the other vmware products, if so, which one.

Note that I have no need to create additional VMs, these are VMs that are being given to me by companies that want us to develop software for their products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that what I needed to do was switch from vmplayer to vmserver.  Which was easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in player, but it requires a bit of work and is probably unsupported. **Here are the instructions for doing this in Windows**, there is likely a better way to do it in Ubuntu, but I can't test it right now.

1. Stop any running VMs and close VMware Player
2. If you no longer have it, download the player installation file.
3. Open a command prompt and cd to the directory that the file is in
4. Run a command that will extract the files in the installer, but not actually run it: `VMware-player-3.0.1-227600.exe /e c:\FOO`
5. Open Explorer and browse to the directory you extracted stuff to (c:\FOO, in my case).
6. Double-click on `network.cab`
7. Copy the file `vmnetcfg.exe` to another location on your system (I copied mine to the actual directory that VMware Player is installed, which should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player`). It doesn't really matter where you copy it.
8. Browse to the location of `vmnetcfg.exe` and run it.
9. Use the handy-dandy GUI to change the adapter that VMnet0 is bridged to from "Automatic" to the one you actually want (or, click `Automatic Settings` and uncheck the ones you don't want it to bridge to).
10. Click ok, then restart VMware Player and your VM

Comment: Thanks.  I think server was definitely the way to go for me, but I'm glad to know it can be done in Player.

Answer (score 1):

Just run Vmware utility : `sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg`

Comment: This is the way to do it on a Linux host (as specified in the question) VMware Player 15. It's not necessary to symlink into /usr/bin though, you can run `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg` directly).  The answer lacks some explanation, but when I had the path, the rest is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this in player, or if you even can, but I know Oracle Virtualbox does it very easy and it's free as well. It basically is the same as VMPlayer, you are able to create new VMs, etc, but you can also create snapshots with Virtualbox.

Comment: would VirtualBox play VMs created in VMware?  As I noted above I get my VMs from partners and I can't ask for new ones created in a different technology.